# How to use aspnet mvc helpers and knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a small application that is generated some fields using razor and the typically helpers like @html.textboxfor, now, I need to use knockoutjs, I created a simple viewmodel and put the data-bind attribute with each helper, but the problem is that the value of the field is clean, I think that for the knockout binding the value if the textbox is cleaned and I need use this value, my code is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control ancho_100", @data_bind = "value:name" })
var userViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
}

var model = new userViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because there is no value in the name observable. Normally you would map the model to json. First you change your ViewModel to accept a model which is used to populate the ViewModel.

```
var UserViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(model.Name);
}
```

Then you serialize the asp.net model to json and then pass that into the constructor of your ViewModel. I recommend to declare you models starting with an uppercase letter so that it is distinguished from variables containing a ViewModel object.

```
var model = @Json.Encode(Model);
ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel(model));
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks, I try it and I change to @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); but the two-way binding is not working

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks, the problem with because I'm using it in a partial view, but I fixed it, thanks.